# Argument block definition is required to set argument use the equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value

Tags: packer

Here is the code:

```
packer 
  required_plugins {
    azure = {
      version = ">= 1.0.0"
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/azure"
    }
  }
}

source "azure-arm" "example" {
  managed_image_name                 = "MT-Image"
  managed_image_resource_group_name  = cg

  location                           = eastus

  # Using Azure CLI for authentication
  use_azure_cli_auth = true

  image_offer     = "visualstudio2022"
  image_publisher = "microsoftvisualstudio"
  image_sku       = "20_04-lts-gen2"

  os_type         = "Windows"
  vm_size         = "Standard E2bds v5"
  os_disk_size_gb = 64

  shared_image_gallery_destination {
    resource_group       = cg
    gallery_name         = gallery1
    image_name           = "newimage"
    image_version        = "1.0.1"
    replication_regions  = ["eastus"]
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
}

  build {
    sources = [
      "source.azure-arm.example"
    ]
  provisioner "powershell" {
    inline = ["Remove-WindowsFeature Web-Server", "while ((Get-Service RdAgent).Status -ne 'Running') { Start-Sleep -s 5 }", "while ((Get-Service WindowsAzureGuestAgent).Status -ne 'Running') { Start-Sleep -s 5 }", "& $env:SystemRoot\\System32\\Sysprep\\Sysprep.exe /oobe /generalize /quiet /quit", "while($true) { $imageState = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Setup\\State | Select ImageState; if($imageState.ImageState -ne 'IMAGE_STATE_GENERALIZE_RESEAL_TO_OOBE') { Write-Output $imageState.ImageState; Start-Sleep -s 10  } else { break } }"]
  }
}
```

I tried to modify everything, please suggest the fix, thanks

I have prepared the HCL template to automate image creation in azure compute gallery using packer.

Please see the code above

Comment: You would need to add the exact place where the error is happening to the question for someone to be able to answer. But looking at the code there seems to be an extra closing curly bracket after the `storage_account_type` line.

Comment: Does [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78006978/13567897) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax issue. The opening brace after the word "packer" is missing

```
packer {
  required_plugins {
    azure = {
      version = ">= 1.0.0"
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/azure"
    }
  }
}
```

https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/docs/templates/hcl_templates/blocks/packer#packer-block-syntax